# How to set up bluetooth tethering between a Mac and a verizon nokia 7705?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, tethering

How to set up bluetooth tethering between a Mac and a verizon nokia 7705?

There doesn't seem to be any/much info on this in the search engines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set up the phone as a bluetooth device as you would any device
2. choose Nokia for vendor and Dialup for "phone model"
3. enter **yournumber@vzw3g.com** as the username (e.g. 3213213213@vzw3g.com)
4. enter **vzw** as the password
5. enter **#777** as the phone number
6. click continue
7. from the modem menu choose "connect"

that's it, easy.

Answer (score 1):

Once you pair it with your Nokia using Bluetooth, under "Network" in "System Preferences", you should be able to see either "Bluetooth" or "Bluetooth PAN" or your device name with a BT icon.

You should key in your APN details in there, then getting online after that should not be a problem.

[image]

This worked on my old Nokia E51, I don't see why it shouldn't work on your 7705 if it's using standard Symbian.